# AzerothCore failing to add mods (ModulesLoader.cpp undefined reference to `Addmod_$NAME_masterScripts()` )

Tags: cmake, azerothcore

I can't seem to get mods to link with AzerothCore.

I'm running a new build (pulled today) and it seems to work ok (after building I can connect and play the game).

When I run `./acore.sh docker build`:

They seem to build ok:

```
Scanning dependencies of target modules
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-ah-bot-master/src/AuctionHouseBot.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-ah-bot-master/src/AuctionHouseBotScript.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-ah-bot-master/src/ah_bot_loader.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-individual-xp-master/src/Individual_XP.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-gain-honor-guard-master/src/GHG_loader.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-ah-bot-master/src/cs_ah_bot.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-gain-honor-guard-master/src/GainHonorGuard.cpp.o
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-individual-xp-master/src/IXP_loader.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-solocraft-master/src/SC_loader.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/CMakeFiles/modules.dir/mod-solocraft-master/src/Solocraft.cpp.o
[ 20%] Linking CXX static library libmodules.a
[ 20%] Built target modules
```

But when I get to linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../modules/libmodules.a(ModulesLoader.cpp.o): in function `AddModulesScripts()':
/azerothcore/var/build/obj/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:56: undefined reference to `Addmod_ah_bot_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /azerothcore/var/build/obj/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:57: undefined reference to `Addmod_gain_honor_guard_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /azerothcore/var/build/obj/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:58: undefined reference to `Addmod_individual_xp_masterScripts()'
/usr/bin/ld: /azerothcore/var/build/obj/modules/gen_scriptloader/static/ModulesLoader.cpp:59: undefined reference to `Addmod_solocraft_masterScripts()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/server/worldserver/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/build.make:175: src/server/worldserver/worldserver] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1181: src/server/worldserver/CMakeFiles/worldserver.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

I'm pretty confused about what could be going wrong. I got the mods from the site, all of them said they were currently passing CI. Since all of them are failing (rather than just one) I assume it's something I've done wrong.

I also tried doing `./acore.sh docker clean:build` and then `./acore.sh docker build` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "-master" from folder name